# PHP - how to receive JSON string and email it

Tags: php, json, email

I have a form (from Cognito) that sends a JSON string to my website script, and I want to email the string on. Here is my code:

```
<?php
$to = "stuff@greenery.me.uk";
$subject = 'has JSON arrived yet';
$body = file_get_contents('php://input');
// $body = 'replace the file_get';
$from = 'From: "thos"<thosgreen@gmail.com>';
mail($to, $subject, $body, $from) ;
?>
```

I know the form is sending out JSON because I've intercepted it with RequestBin. I know my script can send email because if if I decomment the line `$body = 'replace the file_get';` it sends an email. So the problem appears to be the statement `$body = file_get_contents('php://input');` - but that's exactly what all the pages I've looked at say is the right command. And since JSON is a string, that ought to be acceptable as a parameter for mailing, but I tried concatenating with an explicit string and that made no difference.

I've compared my code to other code found on SO and elsewhere and it *looks* right, though it obviously isn't. So I'm stumped. What have I done wrong?

Comment: Ooops, forgot to say - my problem is that no email is sent by this script, unless I decomment the line `//  $body = 'replace the file_get';` in which case it does send email.

Comment: What do you see when you `echo file_get_contents('php://input');`

Comment: Manav - if this is happening from a json event then you will not get to see what echo says without dumping to somewhere like debug console.

Comment: make a file called `test.php`, contents: `<?php var_dump(file_get_contents("php://input"));`, then run this curl command: `curl -v -H "Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8" --data-raw "{test:1}" url/test.php` - what does curl output?

Comment: Try dumping the contents of $body to a file using fopen, fwrite and fclose. Make sure that the folder is writeable first. Also, is it possible to use the post  variable that is sent to the page from Cognito using something like this $body = $_POST['posted_variable_name']?

Comment: damn, incorrectly encoded, i meant: `--data-raw "{\"test\":1}"`

Comment: @ hanshenrik: this is on a shared server, doubt whether I can do that :(

Comment: @ MikeyBunny:  hmm. Did that, good idea, and the answer seems to be null. Very puzzling, because RequestBin shows a JSON string when I  send the form output there.

Comment: Well, you're making progress that's the main thing. Does Cognito POST the values to the page?

Comment: @ MikeyBunny yes, their page says POST. There's a full example [here](https://help.cognitoforms.com/webhooks) but that's way into overkill

Comment: Ok. To find out what is being posted to your page add "$params = print_r($_POST, true);" and write that to your file. It may also be worth also adding "$params = print_r($_GET, true);" and then write that to file as well. Let me know what the contents of the file are.

Comment: Also, is Congnito and your website script running on the same domain?

Comment: @ MikeyBunny I get `Array
(
)
` for both POST and GET.  MikeyB and everyone, thank you for your time, but I think I need to talk to Cognito at this point and see whether it's something at the form end. Cheers, Thomas

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the enctype of the form ? php://input does not work with a  enctype="multipart/form-data" as stated in the doc. http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php#wrappers.php.input.

Comment: RequestBin says `Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8`; should PHP work with that?

Comment: @ThomasGreen the file_get_contents with php://input method should work with that, yes.